# Using this.getApplicationContext(); with multiple application classes

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-context, android-application-class

In my app i need to store the location to firebase so im using two location classes as application because i need to store location for two different entities

First Application class

```
public class FirstApplicationClass  extends MultiDexApplication implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener{ 
}
```

Second Application Class

```
public class SecondApplicationClass extends FirstApplicationClass implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
}
```

Below is manifest.xml code

```
<application
    android:name=".location.SecondApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

i need to use this.getApplicationContext(); in both the case, in the second case where i am using the Second application class, i am able to use  this.getApplicationContext(); from the specific activity i.e,

```
mSecondApplicationClass = (SecondApplicationClass) this.getApplicationContext();
```

and able to store the location.
I dont know how to use this.getApplicationContext(); with the First Application Class, i.e,

```
mFirstApplicationClass = (FirstApplicationClass) this.getApplicationContext();
```

i am unable to  achieve this

Comment: `Second Application Class` ? i dont see any application class extension in `SecondApplicationClass`

Comment: Your second 'Application class' is not an application class. If it was, it would have derived from `Application` or (as your other application class) `MultiDexApplication`. The second is deriving from a `LocationService` (which is probably a service and therefore a context) that's why you can call `getApplicationContext()`. You don't need to call that in `FirstApplicationClass` because that instance is returned when you call `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistke

Answer (score 0):

In an android app, `ApplicationContext` is **unique**

There is no difference between `ApplicationContext` in your `FirstApplicationClass` or `SecontApplicationClass`.

in `AndroidManifest.xml` file you are introducing the `SecondApplicatoinClass` as the application class of your app in this line:

> android:name=".location.SecondApplicationClass"

so your `FirstApplicationClass` is not introduced as the application class of your app and you can not get it's `ApplicationContext`.

change your `AndroidManifest.xml` code to this and you will be able to get `ApplicationContext` in your `FirstApplicationClass`:

```
<application
android:name=".location.FirstApplicationClass  "
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

then you can consume the `ApplicationContext` in both case.

Comment: But since public class SecondApplicationClass extends FirstApplicationClass, the second application class needed to be mentioned in the manifest right? I'm getting an error when I changed the manifest. error  FirstApplicationClass cannot be cast to com.location.SecondApplicationClass because I'm using -  mSecondApplicationClass = (SecondApplicationClass) getActivity().getApplicationContext();

Comment: @MIDHUNCEASAR
you should use just one class as the application class in your application. if you just need the `applicationContext`you can get it in `FirstApplicationClass`'s `onCreate()` method and store it as a static object so you will be able to use it in any class. then create two different classes to imlement `GoogleApiClient`'s callBack and implement methods to get and store location and when is needed you can use the static context you stored in `FirstApplicationClass`